# How to clear all caches for outgoing API requests made from my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, heroku

I have a rails app on heroku that fetches a README.md file from a github repo. I am directly fetching them using the `HTTParty` gem, but looks like all requests are cached if I hit the same URL.

This doesn't clear unless I restart the entire rails app. I would like to be able to clear the cache so that each request I make to fetch the README.md returns a fresh result.

**So the question: How can I clear cache content for all requests my rails app make to external URLs?**

p.s. I know I should be using APIs but I am using APIs for other purposes for the same app and I am trying to minimize the usage of my APIs so I don't reach the limit.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
heroku run rails console
heroku run rake tmp:clear
```

Then run the below commands

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

if you any question please let me know.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without touching the heroku command or restarting? I need to clear cache everytime this event happens and don't want this to be a heavy task...

Comment: Are you using any caching tool like redis or tool?

Comment: nope, i think this is because i'm hitting a static file on github and github has some sort of caching for their files. But i'm trying to find a way to just bypass all that and get the fresh content every time